# How can I make a div appear only when a specific element gets clicked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an HTML with multiple clickable Bootstrap panels. I want that, when a certain div/panel is clicked, only specific divs appear, like specific, with a *class*, to **that** panel.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
//document.ready
$(function () {

    if ($("#panel_1").data("clicked")) {
        alert("yes");
        $(".buscadoresInternet").show();
    } else {
        $(".buscadoresInternet").hide();
    }

    $("#panel_1").click(function () {
        $("#panel_1").data('clicked', true);
        alert("hes");
        console.log($("#panel_1").data("clicked"));
    });



    $("div [id^=panel_]").click(function () {
        //Esconde todos los divs con id = panel_n EXCEPTO el que fue clickeado
        $("div [id^=panel_]").not(this).toggle(function () { });
    })
 });
```

2° stuff is where my logic fails. In my mind, when panel/div with id panel_1 gets clicked, it stores its value like *true*, which works since it appears in the console.

Then, I'm just using a simple if statement, but neither the alert or the div I need to *.show();* appears.

Comment: Just use default jQuery .toggle()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a function for this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel_1").click(function(){
        $(".buscadoresInternet").toggle();
    });
});
```

The `toggle()` function shows the element if it's hidden and hides the element if it's visible.